# Php ajax call for same php script response null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am developing a single page script i.e. category.php for category management.

1. This script have an input button to invoke AJAX call.

> ```
> <input type="button" id="btn" />
> ```

1. Jquery code to bind click event and call ajax. I want json response.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('#btn').click(function(e) {
           id=1;
           jQuery.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: 'category.php',
           success: function(data) {
               if(data.rstatus==1){
               alert(data.text);   
           }else
           alert(data);
       },
           data:{'id':id}


       }); 
       }); 
   });
   ```
2. A php code to entertain AJAX call.

   ```
   if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
       $jsonResponse=array('rstatus'=>1,'id'=>$_POST['id']);
       header("Content-type: application/json");   
       json_encode($jsonResponse);
       die(); 
    }
   ```

Problem:

This ajax call is unable to produce correct response in call back function, and cause error in firebug console.
TypeError: data is null

In FIREBUG Headers are as follow:

> `Response Headers`

```
> Cache-Control no-cache, must-revalidate Connection    Keep-Alive
> Content-Length    0 Content-Type  application/json Date   Tue, 26 Mar 2013
> 12:45:52 GMT Expires  Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
> Keep-Alive    timeout=5, max=98 Last-Modified Tue, 26 Mar 2013
> 12:45:52GMT Pragma    no-cache Server Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c
> PHP/5.4.7 X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.7
```

> `Request Headers`

```
> > Accept  */* Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
>     > Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5 Content-Length   4
>     > Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>     > Cookie  __gads=ID=39701a3d85dce702:T=1350383638:S=ALNI_MY_rHGVQ-qNxH4UGmbY_G-IuVcDkA;
>     > __utma=141011373.593047819.1350426838.1364292528.1364295112.314;PHPSESSID=1s73cho6ildjt80jtudt8nq0f5 Host   abc.com Referer http://www.abc.com/category.php
>     > User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101
>     > Firefox/19.0 X-Requested-With   XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: A well-asked question

Comment: as said, forgot the response (use echo)

also HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH is not the best way to detect ajax request (most of all in case of jQuery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's look like your response content is empty. You forgot an `echo`.

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $jsonResponse=array('rstatus'=>1,'id'=>$_POST['id']);
    header("Content-type: application/json"); 
    echo json_encode($jsonResponse); 
    die(); 
}
```

If you want to response a json, you must put it in the response content. In Php, you just have to use `echo` to put something in the response content.

Comment: good catch. As i reproduce this code for SO question and real implementation is vary complex, so i think this is just a typo and i use echo in original code, I will accept answer after some test with original code. or ask for more help.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work simply because `$_SERVER` doesn't contain that information. All request headers aren't really stored there. Have a look at `getallheaders` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php)

Edit: Oh, also you need to echo the response. $_SERVER may contain the information you need in this case, but it is not reliable and portable. I'd still advise you to use getallheaders

Comment: I found this in $_SERVER ARRAY.  Array
(
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    [HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] => XMLHttpRequest
   . and many other
)

Comment: Also i am using jQuery and am sure it produce $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']

Comment: @Asadkamran The guy who didn't ask the question didn't specify the OS, but it is not considered a good practice to read headers from $_SERVER as it is dependent on the way php is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

don't use HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH - barely works in jQuery
try to send additional var, like

data:{'id':id, 'request':'xmlhttprequest'}

Comment: yes, i am thinking of it to validate the request using some token mechanism.